# Android: App that runs in background drain battery

Tags: android, service, background, battery, powermanager

I made an app that connect to my server every 5-10 minutes and check if there is some change in database.

So i use Service so that app can run in background and that user can close app and get messages in status bar. Inside of it i use Thread so that app sleeps for 5-10 minutes. The problem begins when i lock the phone. than  app just stops (this is because when you lock your  phone goes to "sleep"), so i figured out that i need this:

```
PowerManager pm = (PowerManager) getSystemService(Context.POWER_SERVICE);
wl = pm.newWakeLock(PowerManager.PARTIAL_WAKE_LOCK, 'My Tag');      
wl.acquire();
```

That forces phone not to go sleep except the screen. But there i stuck. This works fine, but drains the battery to much. 10% per hour :( And i believe that there is not a problem that app have to make those web services request all the thime but that function which force that phone to be alive.

So, my question is, if there is any other solution that i can use, because i have some app on phone that runs in backgorund but they do not drains battery so much at all (avast, juice defender, etc..).

Any idea is very helpfull!

regards!

Answer (score 1):

What about using a push mechanism, such as [C2DM for Android](http://code.google.com/intl/es-ES/android/c2dm/), instead of polling all the time.

Answer (score 1):

Google I_O 2009 - Coding for Life -- Battery Life, That Is

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OUemfrKe65c

this will answer your question .

Answer (score 1):

You have to release wakelocks as soon as possible. Do not use them. Instead try Broadcast receiver and AlarmManger to do what you want.

Answer (score 1):

Alarm manager and Broadcst receiver are your friends.   And you may also think about, how important are changes in status bar in case phone lies deep in ass-pocket of throusers. Is thos impdate such important,  that it has to happen even in this case?

Answer (score 0):

You could  set up a AlarmManager with RTC flag for every 5 minutes to launch a Service(Maybe IntentService is better), inside Service Acquire wakelock while doing network operations and stop the service as soon as you are done.